# Is there any circumstance we should cut off the "Y" when adding the "ING" to a verb?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, ing

This question raised when a colleague told me that the correct way of writing *bully* + *-ing* is *bullying*, rather than *bulling*.

Initially I thought that the *-y-* should be kept only when the verb ended with in consonant-vowel-consonant. My assumption was based on the verbs *enjoy* and *say* whose present-participle forms are *enjoying* and *saying*.

However, some time later I realized there were other verbs, not ending in consonant-vowel-consonant, that kept the *-y-*, such as *studying, applying, crying and trying*...

Currently, I imagine there is no such grammar rule and I mixed the plural rules with verb rules. Nevertheless I'd like to get a confirmation. Can anyone help me clarify (another example: *clarifying*) that?

Comment: Have you found *any* verb which drops the *y* in the infinitive? If not, presumably there is no such rule.

Comment: No, I haven't. However, as I'm not a native english speaker, I'd like to confirm that with the experts ;-)

Comment: So what made you think that " the y should be kept only when the verb ended with cvc (consonant-vowel-consonant)"? I know you said your "assumption was based on enjoy and say", but what made you think that they were an exception?

Comment: I've mentioned that on the question... "I think mixed the plural rules with verb rules", in the plural there are a CVC rule, there aren't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a matter of spelling; it's a matter of **pronunciation**.

(1) If the infinitive of the verb ends in /-i/ after a consonant, like

> *bully, caddy, worry, baby, lobby, remedy, ready, tidy, atrophy, jimmy, shinny, pony, copy, cosy*

then the *-ing* form of the verb ends in /-iyɪŋ/. And is spelled *-ying* to remind one of that.

(2) if the infinitive of the verb ends in /-ay/ after a consonant, like

> *spy, descry, reply*

then the *-ing* form of the verb ends in /-ayɪŋ/. And is spelled *-ying* to remind one of **that**.

Isn't English spelling fun?

Comment: John. I'm confused by your answer. I don't understand pronunciation symbols, so I'm leaving those aside. If I understand you correctly, you're saying that both your groups (1) & (2) form the *-ing* form (spelling-wise) by simply adding *-ing* to the infinitive already ending in *-y*. How then can the same ending *-ying* remind one of two different pronunciations?

Comment: @TrevorD: > "How then can the same ending _-ying_ remind one of two different pronunciations?" You seem to be laboring under the false assumption that English spelling has a consistent relation with English pronunciation. It doesn't; it's just there to remind you of things, like Chinese characters. These are two of them, that's all. (You can't discuss English phonetics in print, btw, without resorting at least to phonemic representation; [here's all you need for English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf) on two pages.)

Comment: John, We may be at cross-purposes. I know full well that spelling and pronunciation bear little relationship to one another - but that was my point. You seemed to be saying that, in one case, the spelling reminds one of one particular pronunciation, whereas in the other case the *same* spelling reminds one of a *different* pronunciation. That's what confused me. Or were you just being 'sarcastic' (not quite the right word, but I can't think of another)? Thanks for the link.

Comment: No, I was merely pointing out that if the Y at the end of _cry_ reminds you of the /ay/ pronunciation, then it will do so also in the present participle form _crying_; and ditto for the Y at the end of _hurry_ reminding you of /i/, in the infinitive and in the _-ing_ form. It's no more consistent than the Water Radical or the Fire Radical in Chinese, but like them it's helpful as a memory cue.

Comment: John, you should probably warn people that **you are not using IPA**: you write /y/ for /j/. Makes one wonder how you write /y/.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any circumstance where you would remove the y when using the present participle tense (adding "ing"). I looked up a list of verbs ending in "y" and couldn't find a single one that I'd change. http://verbs1.com/end-y/

There is variation when using past tense, i.e. bully -> bullied; enjoy -> enjoyed.

Comment: There [is] variation?  Also, the "Y" is not changed to "I" in the word "enjoy" in the past tense ("enjoyed").  Other words that do drop the "Y" include sully (sullied), putty (puttied), party (partied), sally (sallied), and many more.

Comment: Only with the past tense suffix, though, which has an initial **-e**. The present participle form has an initial **- i**, and double I's are not good spelling in English, so the Y is retained for contrast there.

Comment: @user47430 I think this answer doesn't meet op's question.